# Maintaining True Scale for the SVG images in Web application

Tags: html, svg

My team is developing an application that requires a few SVGs to be true scale regardless of screen size. We are now manually scaling the SVGs to true scale while we figure out a logic to maintain the scale automatically. When doing the changes manually, I found that only the Canvas of the SVG changes when the Height and Width of the SVG in the database are changed. When I increase the dimensions, the canvas expands, and the SVG just repositions itself to fit within the canvas; when I reduce the dimensions, the SVGs shrink to fit within the canvas. How do I resize the SVGs as well along with canvas?

Comment: Hi. To be able to help, you need to provide some of your code - the SVG output, maybe together with the HTML context. Ideally in the form of [a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do your SVGs have a viewBox? If not, add that parameter to the root svg element with appropriate values.